# Can we debug Java programs with no main method?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, documentum6.5

We have a vast Documentum application which I have deployed in Tomcat. The code is being maintained and compiled in Eclipse IDE.

It is very hard to track where and what data is going through which code, I have a decompiler plugin to help with this task, but it does not work with most of my code as the classes are without a main method. These classes cannot be decompiled by the plugin.

Is there any method to overcome this? So that I can see the flow of data from JSP to backend class to repository, and vise versa.

Answer (score 6):

Sure. You can either connect to tomcat using remote debugging (see [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing)) or run tomcat into eclipse itself. You need appropriate plug-in for this but typically standard eclipse distributions for server side development already have one. Open Servers view, create new server, follow the wizard and you will be done in a minute.

Comment: HI I have configured Tomcat in Eclipse: have few doubts:1) do we need to stop APache from service console in order to start it in Eclipse, as only when APache is stopped in Windows service console it is successfuly startin inside eclipse,  2) if this is the case how will I see my apllication and add dynamic data from JSP and see the flow of data, 3) do I need to create a JAVA EE project Or simple Core JAVA project can also be hosted into Apache inside Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

JPDA is a java standard tool.

It is designed for use by debuggers in any environment on any java application.

For details you can look at

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecbug/

The 1st link gives a detailed view with screen shots of remote debugging using eclipse.